# How to create ND4J NDArrays on GPU in DeepLearning4J?

Tags: java, pytorch, deeplearning4j, dl4j

Is there a way to create NDArrays in DL4J so that the operations are done on GPU ?

For example in pytorch,

```
cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
x = torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=cuda0)
```

I cannot find a way to specify a back-end (`cpu` or `gpu`) if my system is equipped with a GPU ?

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do is include the right nd4j backend version in your pom.xml.
In this case it's generally:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-10.2</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the most recent dl4j version as of this writing. Make sure to double check this on maven central. This will include cuda 10.2

See more here:
https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/config/backends

Comment: I need to pass ```INDArray.data().pointer()``` to my cpp backend. And also I need to create ```NDArray``` using ```libnd4j``` on gpu using ```NDArray``` constructor